# Natural Harmonics on a String

Tags: string, oscillators, wavelength, harmonics

Consider the Dirichlet boundary value problem of a guitar string stretched between two fixed points which is made to oscillate by pinching and releasing the string.

It can be shown in quite straightforward fashion that the solution is given by a Fourier series

$u(x,t) = \bigg( A_n \cos  \frac{n \pi c t}{l} +  B_n \sin  \frac{n \pi c t}{l} \bigg) \sin \frac{n \pi x}{l}.$

The coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ can be related to the initial/boundary conditions. This basically implies that the oscillation of the string would be seen as something quite messy, since there is the dominant overtone which is superposed with various other harmonics.

Is there some way to choose the initial conditions so that something more simple is obtained, for example, so that only the low order terms are kept?

Also, is there a way to set the problem up so that only gets the overtone and the other harmonics are left out of the situation, to achieve

$x(t) =  A \cos (2 \pi f_0 t)    ,$

where $A$ is the amplitude and $f_0$ is the natural frequency.

In the guitar playing world, I think this is called a [natural harmonic](https://allforturntables.com/2023/10/21/what-are-harmonics-on-the-guitar-and-how-are-they-produced/), which is achieved by lightly touching a string at certain points, but I am not sure how this fits in with the mathematical description above.

I appreciate this may sound like a music question, but the answer must have a physical basis.

Comment: The points you touch the strings (the 5th fret and the 12th fret, for instance) correspond to “nice” integer fractions of the length of the string (1/4 and 1/2, respectively). The frequencies you get under the same tension and material with these different lengths will be related to simple harmonics via an easy frequency calculation. In effect, your finger forces distinct nodes to form on the string that give rise to these new frequencies. See the lovely diagram here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-logic-behind-the-fifth-fret-method-and-the-harmonics-method-of-tuning-a-guitar

Comment: @MattHanson So it doesn't matter where you pluck the string to play it, it is always forced into a standing wave configuration by the other finger lightly touching the strong on the correct fret?

Comment: Within reason, yes! You may accidentally cause other effects depending on your picking style and location, but you essentially just cause the frequency associated to the string length where you hold your finger.